# Language selection in the combo

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I configured my servlet to support internationalization, just as I showed below:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

On the JSP page, I added the choice of language in such a way:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>


<h3><spring:message code="label.title"/></h3>

<span style="float: right">
    <a href="?lang=en">en</a>
    |
    <a href="?lang=de">de</a>
</span>
```

How do I replace the above code component of a select (combo)?

(pseudo code)

```
<td><form:select path="language" onchange="">
            <form:option value="0" label="..." />
            <form:options items="${languageList}" />
        </form:select></td>
```

Please help

EDIT
I do not want anything to set as the default. He wants to be chosen this option, he chose you. You will see an example:

The first step
localhost: 8080/newUser
->
In controller

```
@ RequestMapping (value = "/ newuser" method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showNewUser (ModelMap model) {
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView ();
mav.mav.setViewName ("newuser");
User user = new User ();
mav.getModel (). put ("user", user);
return mav;
```

My JSP forms
...

```
<form id="langForm" action="newUse" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
<td> <a href="#"> <spring:message code="label.helpLink" /> </ a> </ td>
<td> <select name="lang" id="lang">
<option value="de"> <spring:message code="languageName.de"> </ spring: message> </ option>
<option value="en"> <spring:message code="languageName.en"> </ spring: message> </ option>
</ select> </ td>
</ tr>
</ table>
</ form>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$ ("# lang"). change (function () {
document.forms ["langForm"] submit ();
});
</ script>
```

The second step
- End-user selects from the combo options "languageName.en. Followed by reloading the page
(localhost: 8080/newUser? lang = en) to change the language to EN but the combo is still selected as the first item. I would like to chose was the one you selected in step 2 So, I would save the state.

ADDED

```
<form>
        <select name="lang" id="lang" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="pl"><spring:message code="languageName.pl"></spring:message></option>
            <option value="en"><spring:message code="languageName.en"></spring:message></option>
        </select>
        </form>
```

How to keep the option without a model?

Comment: I want same functionality i.e dropdown thing. Have you done it ?

Answer (score 0):

in jsp

```
<form:select path="language" onchange="">
<c:forEach var="lan" item="${languageList}">
   <form:option value="0" label="${lan}" />
   <form:options items="${lan}" />
<c:forEach />
</form:select>
```

add javascript that will listen to its change in state. if change occurs reflect this param language in session

**Update:**

Suppose you have combo box like this

```
<select>
  <option>Small</option>
  <option>Medium</option>
  <option>Large</option>
  <option>X-Large</option>
</select>
```

and you want X-large to be selected by default, make HTML like this

```
<select>
  <option>Small</option>
  <option>Medium</option>
  <option>Large</option>
  <option selected="true">X-Large</option>
</select>
```

make it

```
<select name="lang" id="lang">
<option value="de" <c:if ${sessionBean.lan}=='de'>seelcted='true'</c:if>> <spring:message code="languageName.de"> </ spring: message> </ option>
<option value="en"  <c:if ${sessionBean.lan}=='en'>seelcted='true'</c:if>> <spring:message code="languageName.en"> </ spring: message> </ option>
</ select>
```

Comment: in javascript just submit a form and have your language set in session

Comment: I do not know how to do it. I a newbie :-(

Comment: @user612925 add an submit button to the form that a user without java script can handle it, give this butten the id ="btn_langSubmit" and then add then use this form:select `<form:select path="language" onchange="document.getElementById('btn_langSubmit').click();">`

Comment: googling quickly turned into [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)

Comment: Ok It's work. Thanks. But I have another problem. When I change the language of the call is correct and language changes, but the rendered page is always selected as the first item in the combo. How can I keep the state of combos?

Comment: Scenerio 1.  localhost:8080/newUser selected DE 2.User change option to EN 2. Reloading page 3. selected DE !!!. I want : 1.  localhost:8080/newUser 2. User change option to EN 3. selected EN

Comment: thats what I updated , you will have set value in session , read it from there and apply `selected="true"` at proper place

Comment: How can I do this in my Controller?

Comment: How to keep the option without a model? I can?

Comment: what model, can you please precisely list out all your need